# Nexus3 repository URL to be replaced with Nexus2 URL in npm package-lock.json

Tags: npm, nexus, nexus3, nexus2

We have couple of nexus instances, one on nexus 2 and other on nexus 3. Nexus 3 is a proxy of Nexus 2.
Whenever npm builds are run against nexus 3, it adds the repo URL in a different format to the package-lock.json file. When this file is commited to version control and the npm build is run against nexus 2 post commit, the build fails as nexus 2 doesn't identify the nexus3 URL.

We've added below property to nexus.properties file due to which we are able to access the artifacts with nexus 2 URL against nexus2 and nexus3 via browser and maven:
*org.sonatype.nexus.repository.httpbridge.internal.HttpBridgeModule.legacy=true*

However, this has not fixed the issue with URL in package-lock.json file ? Kindly suggest.

Even when npm builds are run against nexus 3, package-lock.json should have the URL in nexus2 format.

Comment: Found this: https://community.sonatype.com/t/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-repository-path-for-url/6157. Looks like the URL can't be changed. However, if any has faced such issue and fixed it , pls let know. Thanks!